# Why does adding `const` to a function type not make `is_const` true?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider these:

```
std::is_const<void() const>::value == false
std::is_same<void() const, std::remove_const_t<void() const>>::value == true
```

I would have thought that the function type `void() const` would be considered `const`.

Why is it not?

Answer (score 4):

Free functions cannot be `const`, so `const` applied to free function types is ignored.

Only member functions can be `const`.

> `[C++14: 8.3.5/6]:` **A *cv-qualifier-seq*** or a *ref-qualifier* **shall only be part of:**
>
> - **the function type for a non-static member function,**
> - the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
> - the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*,
> - the *type-id* in the default argument of a *type-parameter* (14.1), or
> - the *type-id* of a template-argument for a *type-parameter* (14.2).
>
> **The effect of a *cv-qualifier-seq* in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top of the function type. In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored.** *[ Note:* a function type that has a *cv-qualifier-seq* is not a cv-qualified type; there are no cv-qualified function types. *—end note ]* *[..]*

Comment: So how do I strip away this constness? I'm getting a const-qualified free function as a template parameter and I can't make a function pointer of this type: `pointer to function type 'long (int, double) const' cannot have 'const' qualifier
        F* fp;
         ^`

Comment: @user697683: Make it so that you don't get a const-qualified free function as a template parameter. Such a thing does not exist. The problem is at the source!

Comment: _"The effect of a cv-qualifier-seq in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top of the function type. In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored."_- Are that also applied for conversion functions?